# How to pad cell content to center <td>

Tags: html, css

If I have a fixed length text then I can easily center it for example

[image]

However, lets say there are data with variable length,

[image]

Centering the content of Nickname will affect readability. Is there a way to pad the content and centering it base on the longest length?

```
<td>
    <div style="padding-left: 30%;">
       ...content
    </div>
</td>
```

The value "30%" is just rough estimate for nickname.

[image]

However this 30 percent will changed if the column is expecting a longer data. What is a good way to programatically determine this value that I put as "30" ?

Update, centering text is not what I am looking for. I want to center text AND left align, centering text alone will give me

[image]

Visual representation of what I want

[image]

Comment: I think you are looking for a justified alignment, not centered.

Comment: add text-align: center and vertical-align: middle

Comment: I have updated my question, I am not look for centering text. In addition to centering, I want to left align. Its just like a padding effect, but my intention is not to hardcode padded value

Comment: **I want to center text AND left align..** this is absolutely unclear, what do you mean by this? center vertically and left align horizontally?

Comment: @JF-Mechs hi sorry for being unclear. I have updated my visual representation. Hopefully this is clearer.

Comment: do you want center div and left aligned text

Comment: @Zanko that visual representation shows what you really want to accomplish and will help us to fully understand what you need.  But as I look at what you want to accomplish, that would take lots of logic. Vertically aligning them to center and horizantally left doesn't look weird for me.  See example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iam_nash/9swtv88o/)

Comment: @JF-Mechs Initially I left align everything and then I realize it becomes really strange when the table width is set to 100%. http://prnt.sc/bvj99a
There will be alot of white space, and since I am centering the header it makes it even weirder! The link is shown with 30% padded value. It works on small cell but bigger cell the hardcoded 30% becomes obvious

Answer (score 1):

You need javascript to determine the width of the content and the table data width.

```js
 var td = document.querySelectorAll('td > div');
    var width = 0;
    var clientWidth = 0;
    // determine the width
    [].forEach.call(td, function(e) {
      clientWidth = e.parentNode.clientWidth; // the width is the same for all td's
      if (e.clientWidth > width) {
        width = e.clientWidth;
      }
    });
    // set the padding
    [].forEach.call(td, function(e) {
      e.style.paddingLeft = (clientWidth - width) / 2 + 'px';
      e.style.paddingRight = (clientWidth - width) / 2 + 'px';
    });
```

```css
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;    
    }
    th {
      text-align: center;
    }
    th, td {
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    td > div {
      display: inline-block; /* set this because we want to calculate the width, block element has 100% */
      padding: 10px 0;
    }
```

```html
  <table style="width: 50%">
    <tr>
      <th>Nickname</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>Data 1 Data 1Data 1Data 1</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>Data 2</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>Data 3</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>Data 4</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>Data 5</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>Data 6</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>Data 7</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div>Data 8</div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Change the hardcoded table width to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

you can try by mentioning pixels size

```
<td>
    <div style="padding-left: 30px;">
       ...content
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Yes, right now I am hard coding the value as 30%. But it is hard coded. So if I encounter a column with longer with, it might look funny and I have to hard code that particular column to maybe 40% instead. I am just trying to find out a way to programatically do this so it works beautifully for every columns

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Technically this answer is correct but we are unable to see it visually so according to me the best way to do this is to add same left and right padding to both `<th>` and `<td>` and remove `text-align:center` from `<th>`. This is just my opinion. We will wait and see what others think about it. :)

---

Instead of adding padding to one side you need to add it both the sides.

```
table tr td{
      padding:5px 15%;
}
```

I have created a simple example.

```css
table{
  width:200px;
}

table tr th{
  background:#ccc;
  text-align:left;
  padding:5px 15%;
}

table tr td{
  padding:5px 15%;
  background:#eee;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Nickname</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>One</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Big Name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>A Very Big Name</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>This is a very big name</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Oops just saw your image. Will update it after finding the answer

Comment: Thanks! I was just about to say I have tested and it is not what I am looking for : )

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
td{
  padding:5px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so to make it responsive you should use bootstrap 3

try this you will definitely get your answer
[bootstrap tables](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/)

and there classes

```
<tr class="something">
    <td class="col-md-2">A</td>
    <td class="col-md-3">B</td>
    <td class="col-md-6">C</td>
    <td class="col-md-1">D</td>
</tr>
```